# Concat with multiple conditions in MongoDB/Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement a MongoDB query to group and count data in ranges. I found a  wonderful post from Lee Sherwood explaining how to achieve this and reused it with my database. The problem is that I'm working with Spring and I need to write it using Java. I managed to correctly write two parts of the aggregation, but I'm stuck with this one:

```
$project: {
    "range": {
        $concat: [
            { $cond: [{ $and:[ {$gt:["$dose", 0 ]}, {$lt: ["$dose", 50]}]}, "0-50", ""] },
            { $cond: [{ $and:[ {$gt:["$dose", 50 ]}, {$lt: ["$dose", 100]}]}, "50-100", ""] },
            { $cond: [{ $and:[ {$gt:["$dose", 100 ]}, {$lt: ["$dose", 150]}]}, "100-150", ""] },
            { $cond: [{ $and:[ {$gt:["$dose", 150 ]}, {$lt: ["$dose", 200]}]}, "150-200", ""] },
            { $cond: [{ $and:[ {$gt:["$dose", 200 ]}, {$lt: ["$dose", 250]}]}, "200-250", ""] },
            { $cond: [{ $and:[ {$gt:["$dose", 250 ]}, {$lt: ["$dose", 300]}]}, "250-300", ""] },
            { $cond: [{ $gte:["$dose", 300] }, "300+", ""]}
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my code right now:

```
    ProjectionOperation.ProjectionOperationBuilder projectBuilder = Aggregation.project().and("dose");
    for (int startRange = 0; startRange <= 350; startRange += step) {
        int endRange = startRange + step;
        projectBuilder.concat(...)
    }
    return projectBuilder.as("range");
```

How do you write the concat part containing all the conditions?

Comment: Use Switch Case: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/switch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this using a switch statement and conditionals. I have written an example with 1 case below. Add as many cases as needed to satisfy your range requirements.

```
List<AggregationOperation> operationList = new ArrayList<>();
List<ConditionalOperators.Switch.CaseOperator> cases = new ArrayList<>();
ConditionalOperators.Switch.CaseOperator cond1 = ConditionalOperators.Switch.CaseOperator
    .when(BooleanOperators.And.and(
        ComparisonOperators.valueOf("dose").greaterThanValue(0), 
        ComparisonOperators.valueOf("dose").lessThanValue(50)))
    .then("0-50");
cases.add(cond1);

ProjectionOperation projectionOperation = Aggregation.project()
    .and(ConditionalOperators.switchCases(cases)).as("range");
operationList.add(projectionOperation);

System.out.println(aggregation.toString());
```